# ngResource treating POST like GET

Tags: angularjs, post, save, factory, ngresource

I noticed that although I specify "post" on my ngResource factory, it is passing parameters as GET.

Example of a user factory:

```
myApp.factory('facUser',['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/User/:route', {}, {
        EditUser: { method: 'POST', isArray: true, params: { route: "EditUser", cid: '@cid', objEditUser: '@objEditUser' } }
    })
}]);
```

And this is the call to edit the user:

```
$scope.Edited_User = facUser.EditUser({
        cid: $stateParams.company_id, objEditUser: TempUserInfo
    }, function success(data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function err(data, status, headers, config) {
});
```

Thus, when I call that, for some reason I see all my values being passed on the header of the API as if it was a GET.

I am having trouble figuring out how to use $save() or how to post/put this as form.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. Maybe you could create a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) that exhibits the same problem for others to take a look for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` keyword will resolve any route variable and the rest will be in the request query.

To send values in the request body you can do:

```
var user = new User( {
        cid: $stateParams.company_id,
        objEditUser: TempUserInfo
    }) ;
user.$EditUser();
```

And change your resource to be something like:

```
    $resource('/api/User/:route', {}, {
        EditUser: { method: 'POST', isArray: true, params: { route: "EditUser" } }
    })
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.factory('facUser',['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/User/:route', {}, {
        EditUser: { method: 'POST', isArray: true, params: { route: '@route'} }
    })
}]);
```

And then...

```
$scope.Edited_User = facUser.EditUser({
    route: "EditUser"
}, {cid: $stateParams.company_id, objEditUser: TempUserInfo}, function success(data, status, headers) {
   console.log(data);
}, function err(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

Essentially the first part is parameters.

The second part is post values.